# Lenovo X1 Thinkpad Yoga 2nd Ubuntu 22.04.2 - Camera / webcam not working

Tags: usb, lenovo, hp, webcam, camera

USB Camera is not working and tried diff USB ports - sometimes I get lucky and it comes up in cheese or zoom with camera led lighting up - but most of time led light is off. I have this problem on both my
Lenovo Thinkpad X1 2nd Gen Yoga (built in webcam)
and
HP Elitedesk 800 G3 desktop mini (external usb camera)

below is the output for the HP. Any ideas? Thanks

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:08cb Logitech, Inc. Mic (Notebooks Pro)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b0e:0300 GN Netcom Jabra EVOLVE 30 MS
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```